# Weird warning: "Class "BaloShulker" is never used"

Tags: kotlin

`BaloShulker` was my main class for my plugin, it contain every single function inside it.

```kotlin
class BaloShulker : JavaPlugin(), Listener {
   override fun onEnable() {
      ...
   }

   override fun onDisable()
      ...
   }
}
```

My plugin perfectly works but somehow I keep getting this warning: `Class "BaloShulker" is never used`

If you are asking for my full code, here it is:

```kotlin
package me.hoangxuanlam2007.baloshulker

import org.bukkit.Bukkit
import org.bukkit.ChatColor
import org.bukkit.Material
import org.bukkit.block.ShulkerBox
import org.bukkit.command.Command
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration
import org.bukkit.entity.Player
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler
import org.bukkit.event.HandlerList
import org.bukkit.event.Listener
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryCloseEvent
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryDragEvent
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerDropItemEvent
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent
import org.bukkit.inventory.EquipmentSlot
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.BlockStateMeta
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin
import java.io.*
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.util.*


class BaloShulker : JavaPlugin(), Listener {

    private lateinit var customMessages: FileConfiguration

    private val droppedItemTimestamp = HashMap<Player, Long>()

    // Get plugin description
    private val pluginVersion = this.pluginMeta.version
    private val pluginName = this.name

    // Default Plugin prefix
    private fun format(message: String): String {
        return "§7[ §5Balo§dShulker §7] §f»§r $message"
    }

    override fun onEnable() {
        // Register the event listener
        server.pluginManager.registerEvents(this, this)

        // Log a message to the console when the plugin is enabled
        Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(format(ChatColor.GREEN.toString() + "Plugin enabled!"))
        Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(format(ChatColor.GREEN.toString() + "You are using $pluginName v$pluginVersion!"))

        // Load or create messages.yml
        val dataFolder = dataFolder // Assuming dataFolder is the plugin's data folder
        if (!dataFolder.exists()) {
            dataFolder.mkdirs() // Create the necessary directories
        }

        // messages.yml
        val customMessagesFile = File(dataFolder, "messages.yml")
        if (!customMessagesFile.exists()) {
            try {
                customMessagesFile.createNewFile()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            // Add comment for easier configuration
            try {
                val writer = BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(FileOutputStream(customMessagesFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                writer.write("# ===================================================================================================================|")
                writer.newLine()
                writer.write("# > This Plugin is coded privately by ChimmFX aka Hoàng Xuân Lâm. <")
                writer.newLine()
                writer.write("# - This plugin works better than ShulkerPack with more configurations including custom messages.")
                writer.newLine()
                writer.write("# - Feel safe to use this plugin!")
                writer.newLine()
                writer.write("#")
                writer.newLine()
                writer.write("# - There are 3 permissions that work perfectly with any permissions plugin, such as LuckPerm:")
                writer.newLine()
                writer.write("#     + baloshulker.use")
                writer.newLine()
                writer.write("#     + baloshulker.info")
                writer.newLine()
                writer.write("#     + baloshulker.reload")
                writer.newLine()
                writer.write("# - These permissions work as their names suggested.")
                writer.newLine()
                writer.write("#")
                writer.newLine()
                writer.write("# For further information, to report bugs, or to contact me, email: chim31102007@gmail.com")
                writer.newLine()
                writer.write("# Author Github: https://github.com/hoangxuanlam2007")
                writer.newLine()
                writer.write("# ===================================================================================================================|")
                writer.newLine()
                writer.newLine()
                writer.newLine()
                writer.newLine()
                writer.flush()
                writer.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            customMessages = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(customMessagesFile)

            // Set default messages
            setDefaultMessage("command_usage", "§cUse §7<§f/bs help§7> §cfor help.")
            setDefaultMessage("command_unknown", "§cUnknown command. Use §7<§f/bs help§7> §cfor help.")
            setDefaultMessage("permission_required", "§cYou don't have permission to use this command!")
            setDefaultMessage("low_tps", "§cThe server TPS is currently too low to open the BaloShulker!")
            setDefaultMessage("help_header", "§d§m ‡         §8(§5Balo§dShulker §eHelp§8)§d§m         ‡")
            setDefaultMessage("help_line_1","§7  [§fRight_Click§7] §7: Open Shulker box.")
            setDefaultMessage("help_line_2","§7   <§f/bs help§7> §7: Show command help.")
            setDefaultMessage("help_footer","§d§m ‡                                         ‡")

            try {
                customMessages.save(customMessagesFile)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        } else {
            customMessages = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(customMessagesFile)
        }
    }

    private fun setDefaultMessage(key: String, defaultValue: String) {
        if (!customMessages.contains(key)) {
            customMessages.set(key, ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', defaultValue))
            try {
                customMessages.save(File(dataFolder, "messages.yml"))
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getMessage(key: String): String {
        val message = customMessages.getString(key, "") ?: ""
        return ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', message)
    }

    override fun onDisable() {
        // Specify the Listener overload
        HandlerList.unregisterAll(this as Listener)

        // Log a message to the console when the plugin is disabled
        Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(format(ChatColor.RED.toString() + "Plugin disabled!"))
    }

    private val openedShulkers = HashMap<Player, ItemStack>()

    // Map to store custom titles for each colored shulker box
    private val shulkerBoxTitles = mapOf(
            Material.SHULKER_BOX to "§dBalo Shulker", // Default title for the regular shulker box
            Material.WHITE_SHULKER_BOX to "§fBalo Shulker trắng",
            Material.ORANGE_SHULKER_BOX to "§6Balo Shulker cam",
            Material.MAGENTA_SHULKER_BOX to "§dBalo Shulker hồng sậm",
            Material.LIGHT_BLUE_SHULKER_BOX to "§bBalo Shulker xanh lam nhạt",
            Material.YELLOW_SHULKER_BOX to "§eBalo Shulker vàng",
            Material.LIME_SHULKER_BOX to "§aBalo Shulker xanh lá mạ",
            Material.PINK_SHULKER_BOX to "§dBalo Shulker hồng",
            Material.GRAY_SHULKER_BOX to "§8Balo Shulker xám",
            Material.LIGHT_GRAY_SHULKER_BOX to "§7Balo Shulker xám nhạt",
            Material.CYAN_SHULKER_BOX to "§3Balo Shulker xanh lơ",
            Material.PURPLE_SHULKER_BOX to "§5Balo Shulker tím",
            Material.BLUE_SHULKER_BOX to "§9Balo Shulker xanh nước biển",
            Material.BROWN_SHULKER_BOX to "§6Balo Shulker nâu",
            Material.GREEN_SHULKER_BOX to "§2Balo Shulker xanh lá",
            Material.RED_SHULKER_BOX to "§cBalo Shulker đỏ",
            Material.BLACK_SHULKER_BOX to "§0Balo Shulker đen"
    )

    private val droppedShulkerBoxes = HashMap<Player, Int>()

    @EventHandler
    fun onPlayerInteract(event: PlayerInteractEvent) {
        val player = event.player
        val action = event.action
        val hand = event.hand
        val item = if (hand == EquipmentSlot.HAND) player.inventory.itemInMainHand else player.inventory.itemInOffHand

        // Check if the player is sneaking (shift key pressed) and holding a shulker box
        val isSneaking = player.isSneaking

        // Check if the player is holding a shulker box and right-clicked or touched and held
        if (isShulkerBox(item) && (action == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) && !isSneaking) {
            // Check if the player recently dropped the same shulker box (within the last 1 second)
            val lastDropTime = droppedItemTimestamp.getOrDefault(player, 0L)
            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastDropTime) < 1000) {
                val droppedSlot = droppedShulkerBoxes[player]
                if (droppedSlot != null) {
                    val slotItem = player.inventory.getItem(droppedSlot)
                    if (slotItem != null && slotItem == item) {
                        return
                    } else {
                        // Close the shulker box GUI
                        player.closeInventory()
                        return
                    }
                }
            }

            // Check if the TPS is above a certain threshold
            val tps = Bukkit.getTPS()[0]
            if (tps >= 18 && tps <= 20) {
                // Open the shulker box
                openShulkerBox(player, item)

                // Store the shulker box being opened and the slot
                val openedSlot = player.inventory.heldItemSlot
                droppedShulkerBoxes[player] = openedSlot
            } else {
                // Inform the player that the TPS is too low for instant interaction
                player.sendMessage(format(getMessage("low_tps")))
            }
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    fun onPlayerDropItem(event: PlayerDropItemEvent) {
        // Record the timestamp when a player drops an item
        droppedItemTimestamp[event.player] = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }

    private fun isShulkerBox(item: ItemStack): Boolean {
        return item.type in shulkerBoxTitles.keys
    }

    private val openedShulkerSlots = HashMap<Player, Int>()

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION") // Fix weirdo deprecation from paper api
    private fun openShulkerBox(player: Player, shulkerBoxItem: ItemStack) {
        val shulkerBoxMeta = shulkerBoxItem.itemMeta as? BlockStateMeta

        if (shulkerBoxMeta != null && shulkerBoxMeta.blockState is ShulkerBox) {
            val shulkerBox = shulkerBoxMeta.blockState as ShulkerBox
            val shulkerBoxMaterial = shulkerBoxItem.type

            // Set the custom title for each colored shulker box
            val title = shulkerBoxTitles[shulkerBoxMaterial] ?: "§fBalo Shulker"

            shulkerBox.customName = title
            player.openInventory(shulkerBox.inventory)

            // Store the shulker box item when it is opened
            openedShulkers[player] = shulkerBoxItem

            // Store the slot index of the opened shulker box
            openedShulkerSlots[player] = player.inventory.heldItemSlot
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    fun onInventoryClose(event: InventoryCloseEvent) {
        val player = event.player as? Player

        // Check if the player has a shulker that was previously opened
        if (player != null && openedShulkers.containsKey(player)) {
            val shulkerBoxItem = openedShulkers[player]
            if (shulkerBoxItem != null) {
                // Store the current state of the shulker box inventory
                saveShulkerContents(shulkerBoxItem, event.inventory.contents)
            }

            openedShulkers.remove(player)

            // Remove the slot index from the map
            openedShulkerSlots.remove(player)
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    fun onInventoryClick(event: InventoryClickEvent) {
        val player = event.whoClicked as? Player

        // Check if the clicked inventory is the player's inventory
        if (player != null && event.clickedInventory == player.inventory) {
            val shulkerBoxSlot = openedShulkerSlots[player]

            // Check if the clicked slot is the opened shulker box slot
            if (shulkerBoxSlot != null && shulkerBoxSlot == event.slot) {
                event.isCancelled = true
            }
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    fun onInventoryDrag(event: InventoryDragEvent) {
        val player = event.whoClicked as? Player

        // Check if the clicked inventory is the player's inventory
        if (player != null && event.inventory == player.inventory) {
            val shulkerBoxSlot = openedShulkerSlots[player]

            // Check if the dragged slots include the opened shulker box slot
            if (shulkerBoxSlot != null && event.rawSlots.contains(shulkerBoxSlot)) {
                event.isCancelled = true
            }
        }
    }

    private fun saveShulkerContents(shulkerItem: ItemStack, contents: Array<ItemStack?>) {
        val shulkerBoxMeta = shulkerItem.itemMeta as? BlockStateMeta

        if (shulkerBoxMeta != null && shulkerBoxMeta.blockState is ShulkerBox) {
            val shulkerBox = shulkerBoxMeta.blockState as ShulkerBox
            shulkerBox.inventory.contents = contents
            shulkerBox.update()
            shulkerBoxMeta.blockState = shulkerBox
            shulkerItem.itemMeta = shulkerBoxMeta
        }
    }

    override fun onCommand(sender: CommandSender, command: Command, label: String, args: Array<out String>): Boolean {
        if (command.name.equals("bs", ignoreCase = true)) {
            if (sender is Player && !sender.hasPermission("baloshulker.use")) {
                sender.sendMessage(format(getMessage("permission_required")))
                return true
            }

            if (args.isNotEmpty()) {
                when (args[0].lowercase(Locale.getDefault())) {
                    "help" -> {
                        // Display help message for /bs help command
                        showHelp(sender)
                    }
                    "info" -> {
                        if (sender.hasPermission("baloshulker.info")) {
                            sender.sendMessage(format("§aYou are using §e$pluginName §av$pluginVersion."))
                        }
                    }
                    "reload" -> {
                        if (sender.hasPermission("baloshulker.reload")) {
                            reloadPlugin()
                            sender.sendMessage(format("§e$pluginName §av$pluginVersion plugin reloaded successfully!"))
                        } else {
                            sender.sendMessage(format("§cYou don't have permission to reload the plugin!"))
                        }
                    }
                    else -> {
                        // Unknown command, show help or error message here
                        sender.sendMessage(format(getMessage("command_unknown")))
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // No arguments provided, show help or error message here
                sender.sendMessage(format(getMessage("command_usage")))
            }
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun showHelp(sender: CommandSender) {
        // Modify this function to show your help message
        sender.sendMessage(getMessage("help_header"))
        sender.sendMessage("")
        sender.sendMessage(getMessage("help_line_1"))
        sender.sendMessage(getMessage("help_line_2"))
        sender.sendMessage("")
        sender.sendMessage(getMessage("help_footer"))
    }

    override fun onTabComplete(sender: CommandSender, cmd: Command, alias: String, args: Array<String>): List<String>? {
        if (cmd.name.equals("bs", ignoreCase = true)) {
            if (args.size == 1) {
                val suggestions = mutableListOf<String>()

                if (sender.hasPermission("baloshulker.use")) {
                    suggestions.add("help") // Add 'help' as a suggestion
                }

                if (sender.hasPermission("baloshulker.info")) {
                    suggestions.add("info") // Add 'help' as a suggestion
                }

                if (sender.hasPermission("baloshulker.reload")) {
                    suggestions.add("reload") // Add 'reload' as a suggestion for users with OP or permission
                }

                return suggestions
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun reloadPlugin() {
        // Unregister listeners and perform any necessary cleanup
        onDisable()

        // Re-register listeners and reinitialize resources
        onEnable()
    }
}

It is too long, kinda hard too read but I'm managing to seperate it into several kotlin class files. Can anyone help me?
```

Comment: If it is not directly referenced anywhere in the code, then IDE/compiler may think it is not used. You can just ignore/suppress this warning.

Comment: how do I supress this? @broot

Comment: Mmmm.  It's the same with any class (or method) which is called only from a framework, which the IDE/compiler isn't aware of — such as Spring `@Controller`s and `@Service`s.